# template specialization, explicit instantiation and forward declarations

Tags: c++, templates

I have some doubts about what the standard says about the following case:

```cpp
//foo.hpp

#pragma once
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
void foo(){
  std::cout << "generic\n";
}

#ifdef FWD
template<>
void foo<int>();
#endif
```

```cpp
//foo.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

template<>
void foo<int>(){
  std::cout << "specialization\n";
}
```

```cpp
\\main.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"

int main(){
  foo<int>();
}
```

The result of this code is the same no matter the definition of FWD (print "specialization"). However, if I check symbols in main.o, results are different:

- FWD defined : undefined symbol to specialization of foo
- FWD undefined : the symbol to foo exists

Is there a standard way of dealing with this? Is there any risk that the general implementation is taken at link-time when no forward declaration is done?

Comment: You might have to explicitly instanciate that template if it not directly used from `foo.cpp` itself...

Comment: @Phil1970 is that really necessary for a fully specialized template?

Comment: Explicit instantiation is a nice thing but is kinda pointless when template code is right there in the header. If the set of types the function will need to operate on is more-or-less well-defined though, it can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any risk that the general implementation is taken at
> link-time when no forward declaration is done?

[[temp.expl.spec]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-7) says as follows:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
> explicitly specialized, a declaration of that specialization shall be
> reachable from every use of that specialization that would cause an
> implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
> which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

Thus without having the explicit specialization *at least* forward declared I would expect UB and inconsistency between compilers.

Moreover, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5ve4xseW5) you can see that the same compiler (in this case clang) works differently depending on optimisation options.

---

**TLDR**: either include definition of the explicit specialization or at least forward declare its existence.